# Asterisk Triangle in Python (using recursion)

Tags: python, recursion

I have seen multiple "python asterisk triangles" and their solutions, but I am stuck on creating an asterisk triangle using recursion (without a loop, which would make it much easier in my opinion.) Below is the current code I have:

```
def main():
    num = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
    triangle = draw_triangle(num)
    print(triangle)


def draw_triangle(n):
    if n == 0:
        return
    else:
        return ("*" * n + '\n') + draw_triangle(n - 1)


main()
```

When I run the code, I receive "TypeError: must be str, not NoneType." I have done some research and still do not completely understand what this error is telling me. I apologize if this question was asked before, I was unable to find one dealing with any recursive functions. Thank you.

Comment: To fix that error, return an empty string for your base case.

Answer (score 0):

`return` to `return ""`

Input: `5`

Output:

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because you return a blank value. Try returning a blank string instead

Solution:
In line 9:
replace `return` with `return ''`

Answer (score 0):

The code is working properly but there is just a slight problem.
When testing with base case i.e. `if n == 0:` the return must be set to something, if not it will return `None`. Thus after the input number reaches 0 it returns `None` anything that returns `None` is interpreted as a failed case in python so 
Here is a work around:

```
def draw_triangle(n):
    if n == 0:
        return ''
    else:
        return ("*" * n + '\n') + draw_triangle(n - 1)

def main():
    num = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
    triangle = draw_triangle(num)
    print(triangle)
main()
```

Thus after reaching `n == 0` case the program will return a blank string and continue.